# How to add new fields in Firestore Document from two different sources simultaneously?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When a new user registers in my app using `firebase-authentication` custom sign in using email and password, I need to update that data into my firestore.
But Firebase only has `FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` to create a new account and hence I cannot update my user's **username** at the same time.

To update the E-Mail in Firestore, I use Firebase cloud functions. Here's the code:

```
export const onNewUserJoined = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    //const newUserDisplayName = user.displayName //CAN'T USE THIS. REASON is BELOW
    const newUserUID = user.uid
    const newUserEmail = user.email
    const timeCreated = Date.now()

    console.log(`${newUserUID} has joined.`)

    return admin.firestore().collection('Agent').doc(`${newUserUID}`).set({"E-Mail": newUserEmail, "Time": timeCreated})               
})
```

OK, great now I have updated the E-Mail and time created in Firestore successfully.

But next challenge is I need to update the user's username in the same Firestore document. I do it instantly after the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` like this:

```
 DocumentReference dDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(documentPath);
 Map<String, Object> updateUsernameAndPhone = new HashMap<>();
 updateUsernameAndPhone.put("username", username);
 updateUsernameAndPhone.put("phoneData", phoneModel);
 dDocRef.update(updateUsernameAndPhone).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data successfully stored in Firestore", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });
```

**Now, it depends on who acts first, the cloud function or the user's device.**

If the cloud functions act first, then there is no issue. The username and phoneModel both get updated into the document successfully. No issues.

But incase, the phone acts first then I get the following error:

[image]

As this error has occurred, username isn't in the document and only email and timeCreated are in the document updated by the cloud function which got late to create document so that user's device can update the username with ease.

**I CAN'T** use `.SET` instead of `.update()` in my app because if I use `.set()` and the cloud functions create the email and timeCreated fields first. Then the device will DELETE them and put username and phoneModel.

So how can I do this?

I can forcefully delay updating the username by putting it in the next activity so that cloud functions get enough time to do their job, but my `signUpActivity` asks for username along with email and password edit texts. I don't want to create a separate activity for that.

I used to use `.update()` when my data was stored in realtime database and it used to create the child even if the path didn't exist. But it looks firestore won't update if the field doesn't exist.

Any solution for this?

I tried as per @DougStevenson said and here's my code:

```
final String newUserUID = Objects.requireNonNull(signUpAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();

final String documentPath = "Agent/" + newUserUID;

FirebaseFirestore fFirestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
final DocumentReference dDocRef = fFirestoreRef.document(documentPath);

fFirestoreRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
@Nullable
@Override
    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws 
    FirebaseFirestoreException {
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = transaction.get(dDocRef);
    transaction.update(dDocRef, "username", username);
    transaction.update(dDocRef, "phoneData", phoneModel);
    return null;
  }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data updated in Firestore . . .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   });
```

But no luck. It still gives me error: `Cannot update a document which does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to resolve conflicts from multiple clients that are all trying to modify the same document.  The transaction handler will be retried on the client if it detects the document was modified before the change could take place.

Comment: Will this solve the issue of updating from android app if the document doesn't exist? Giving it a try right now.

Comment: Yes, you can use a transaction with documents that don't exist, as long as you get() it first.

Comment: I have added my transaction code in my question. I am still getting error as mentioned. Let me elaborate. For example, at 1st second my app tried to update data but finds no such document so gets error. At 2nd second, my cloud function creates the document. But even using transaction it won't retry to update document after 2nd second. I can't use `.set()` because it will delete data created by the cloud function.